# Caliburn.Micro - Passing combobox items to a button

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to pass items from my Combobox (which is binded to my Model object's lists) to my button. My problem is that I'm new to Caliburn.Micro + WPF and not quite sure how to subscribe/pass the desired values to my button (like sending strings of a PropetyName to a Button(string propetyName)).

ViewModel code:

```
class ShellViewModel : Screen
{
    private DataModel _fileInFolder;
    private BindableCollection<DataModel> _data;

    public ShellViewModel()
    {
       // .GetData() preforms the objects'  initialization
        DataModel dataOutput = new DataModel();
        Data = new BindableCollection<DataModel>(dataOutput.GetData());
    }


    public BindableCollection<DataModel> Data 
    {
        get
        {
            return _data;
        }

        set
        {
            _data = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Data);
        }
    } 

    public DataModel FileInFolder
    {
        get { return _fileInFolder; }
        set 
        { 
            _fileInFolder = value;

            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FileInFolder);

        }
    }

   //This is where the items will be passed to.
  
  public void OpenFile()
  {
       
  }

}
```

XAML code:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- Folders -->
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" SelectedItem="{Binding FileInFolder}"
     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Folders}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
    <!-- Files -->
    <ComboBox x:Name="FileInFolder_Files"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="280,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250"/>
    <!-- Open File -->
    <Button x:Name="OpenFile" 
    Content="Open File" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="560,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90">
       
    </Button>

</Grid>
```

Sorry if my description is vague/missing more clarification, I'm a new user here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileInFolder is the selected item of the combo.

OpenFile is in the same class and can therefore reference FileInFolder.

```
public void OpenFile()
{
     var whatever = FileInFolder.SomeProperty;
   // etc
}
```

You probably want some null checking in there.